# How to have swipe and scroll down in HTML, CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am coding a quick template to open on your phone or email (Plain HTML, CSS and JS no framework). It's a brochure type of template.

I can get either functionality to work individually, however when combining them I can only swipe right and left which makes no sense to me.

I am display my HTML as flex in the column direction, so essentially moving from one column to the next. I can see why I can scroll down. Any ideas?

Here is the html :

```
 <div class="slider-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="Microcare.png" alt="">

                <div class="wrapper1">

                    <div class="scroll1">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                       
                    <div class="contact">
                        <a class="btn" href="tel:083-278-5259">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/apple-phone.png"/>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn" href = "mailto: sales@microcare.com">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/email.png"/>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/whatsapp.png"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>                               
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h2>Iphone12</h2>
                <h4>$199</h4>
                <img src="#" alt="">
                <a href ="" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h2>Iphone11</h2>
                <h4>$199</h4>
                <img src="#" alt="">
                <a href ="" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I added images in scroll1 just to test if it worked.

css:

```
 <div class="slider-container">
            <div class="slide">
                <img src="Microcare.png" alt="">

                <div class="wrapper1">

                    <div class="scroll1">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                        <img src="solar.png" alt="">
                    </div>
                       
                    <div class="contact">
                        <a class="btn" href="tel:083-278-5259">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/apple-phone.png"/>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn" href = "mailto: sales@microcare.com">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/email.png"/>
                        </a>
                        <a class="btn">
                            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/color/50/000000/whatsapp.png"/>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>                               
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h2>Iphone12</h2>
                <h4>$199</h4>
                <img src="#" alt="">
                <a href ="" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <h2>Iphone11</h2>
                <h4>$199</h4>
                <img src="#" alt="">
                <a href ="" class="btn">Buy Now</a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
const slider = document.querySelector('.slider-container'),
  slides = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.slide'))

let isDragging = false,
  startPos = 0,
  currentTranslate = 0,
  prevTranslate = 0,
  animationID = 0,
  currentIndex = 0

slides.forEach((slide, index) => {
  const slideImage = slide.querySelector('img')
  slideImage.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => e.preventDefault())

  // Touch events
  slide.addEventListener('touchstart', touchStart(index))
  slide.addEventListener('touchend', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('touchmove', touchMove)

  // Mouse events
  slide.addEventListener('mousedown', touchStart(index))
  slide.addEventListener('mouseup', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('mouseleave', touchEnd)
  slide.addEventListener('mousemove', touchMove)
})

// Disable context menu
window.oncontextmenu = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
  return false
}

function touchStart(index) {
  return function (event) {
    currentIndex = index
    startPos = getPositionX(event)
    isDragging = true

    // https://css-tricks.com/using-requestanimationframe/
    animationID = requestAnimationFrame(animation)
    slider.classList.add('grabbing')
  }
}

function touchEnd() {
  isDragging = false
  cancelAnimationFrame(animationID)

  const movedBy = currentTranslate - prevTranslate

  if (movedBy < -100 && currentIndex < slides.length - 1) currentIndex += 1

  if (movedBy > 100 && currentIndex > 0) currentIndex -= 1

  setPositionByIndex()

  slider.classList.remove('grabbing')
}

function touchMove(event) {
  if (isDragging) {
    const currentPosition = getPositionX(event)
    currentTranslate = prevTranslate + currentPosition - startPos
  }
}

function getPositionX(event) {
  return event.type.includes('mouse') ? event.pageX : event.touches[0].clientX
}

function animation() {
  setSliderPosition()
  if (isDragging) requestAnimationFrame(animation)
}

function setSliderPosition() {
  slider.style.transform = `translateX(${currentTranslate}px)`
}

function setPositionByIndex() {
  currentTranslate = currentIndex * -window.innerWidth
  prevTranslate = currentTranslate
  setSliderPosition()
}
```

Comment: Your document has to take up more height than is available vertically in the viewport in order for it to scroll vertically. Without code, though, there's not much else to say.

Comment: what you actually want ? do you have any code of this

Comment: Please see [ask]. You need to show some code as a point of discussion.

Comment: Sorry about that guys/girls I added the code now.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are looking for swipe and scroll down navbar so here it is or want something else so comment I'll try to answer it**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#navbar {
  background-color: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transition: top 0.3s;
}

#navbar a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

#navbar a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navbar">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<div style="padding:15px 15px 2500px;font-size:30px">
  <p><b>This example demonstrates how to slide down a navbar when the user starts to scroll the page.</b></p>
  <p>Scroll down this frame to see the effect!</p>
  <p>Scroll to the top to hide the navbar.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor dummy text sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>

<script>
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, slide down the navbar
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "0";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("navbar").style.top = "-50px";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```